# CSS: Chrome and Firefox return "undefined" error window

Tags: css, slider

I´m struggling with a loopslider (sliding portfolio) on my page

It works perfectly but Google Chrome is loading this pop-up error window :

And seems to be Firefox is doing it to

[image]

This is the url to my page[enter link description here](http://www.nicejob.is/new)

Any suggestions what the problem might be?

Comment: You have an `alert` statement somewhere, and you're passing an `undefined` value to it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is [here](http://www.nicejob.is/new/js/custom.js)

```
alert('Error preloading image ' . value);
```

Should be:

```
alert('Error preloading image ' + value);
```

Looks like a PHP habit ;)

Answer (score 1):

In custom.js:

```
alert('Error preloading image ' . value);
```

should be

```
alert('Error preloading image ' + value);
```

This is Javascript, not PHP.